# Time difference in C#, 3-digit-format minutes

Tags: c#, time, timestamp

I have a problem calculating difference between two timestamps, when minutes are represented with 3 digits, e.g. 180:22 = 180 minutes and 22 seconds.

So, can you help me how can I get difference between timestamps like:

180:22 and 122:11

or

232:21 and 31:34

etc.

UPDATE: I need to get difference between two times, defined as strings. What makes a problem is that minutes in those strings (times) are larger than 60, and they are over the limit. So I need to know how to find difference like in above examples (180:22 and 122:11, and 232:21 and 31:34)

Comment: Please post some code showing what type these time values actually are: String? DateTime? TimeSpan? ...And what type the resulting difference should be.

Comment: Like DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes or do you have only the minute and second portions represented in some peculiar ways without the date part?

Answer (score 1):

Use [System.TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.timespan.aspx) structures:

```
var seconds=(new TimeSpan(0, 180, 22)-new TimeSpan(0, 122, 11)).TotalSeconds;
var minutes=(new TimeSpan(0, 232, 21)-new TimeSpan(0, 31, 34)).TotalMinutes;
```

Comment: I don't agree. var seconds=3491, var minutes=200,783333333333. The results are correct.

Comment: @McKay Would you provide an example that yields an incorrect result?

Comment: according to @CédricBelin seconds = 3491. That doesn't appear to be in the correct format. Or do you not care about the format?

Comment: Also, this code doesn't actually take things in the format specified. It is just doing time math. But maybe that's what the OP wants?

Comment: I don't care about the format: the result of the difference of two TimeSpan is also a TimeSpan. So, you can format this result as you want. EDIT: like this for example => string.Format("{0}:{1}", result.Minutes, result.Seconds)

Comment: I know you don't care about the format. Your answers seem to reflect that. But maybe the poster does care about format.

Comment: @McKay: it's maybe the case. But I prefer to teach the concept of a time difference, instead of giving the full answer.

Comment: @CédricBelin And if that's all you want to write about, fine, but I believe the OP is asking for more. There are three distinct steps that he might want: 1) Interpreting the string, 2) performing the subtraction, 3) formating the result. This answer clearly covers the middle step, I think he wants all three. The question actually asked definitely speaks to the first two. I believe this answer is incomplete.

Comment: @McKay: The question is clearly about the steps 1 and 2. I don't see any mention about the format of the result. But you're right: my answer don't take step 1 into account.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a class that will do this stuff:

```
public class CrazyTime
{
    public TimeSpan TimeSpanRepresentation { get; set; }
    public CrazyTime(TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        this.TimeSpanRepresentation = timeSpan;
    }
    public CrazyTime(string crazyTime)
    {
        // No error checking. Add if so desired
        var pieces = crazyTime.Split(new[] { ':' });
        var minutes = int.Parse(pieces[0]);
        var seconds = int.Parse(pieces[1]);
        TimeSpanRepresentation = new TimeSpan(0, minutes, seconds);
    }
    public static CrazyTime operator-(CrazyTime left, CrazyTime right)
    {
        var newValue = left.TimeSpanRepresentation - right.TimeSpanRepresentation;
        return new CrazyTime(newValue);
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        // How should negative Values look?
        return ((int)Math.Floor(TimeSpanRepresentation.TotalMinutes)).ToString() + ":" + TimeSpanRepresentation.Seconds.ToString();
    }
}
```

Here's how it might be used:

```
        var a = new CrazyTime("123:22");
        var b = new CrazyTime("222:11");
        var c = b - a;
        Console.WriteLine(c);
```

Comment: I like the use of string.Split().

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
string time1 = "180:22";
string time2 = "122:11";

TimeSpan span1 = getTimespan(time1);
TimeSpan span2 = getTimespan(time2);

TimeSpan diff = span1 - span2;
```

getTimespan just has to correctly parse the string. I decided on Regex to do that, but you could go any route, particularly if the delimiter ":" isn't ever going to change.

```
private static TimeSpan getTimespan(string time1)
{
    Regex reg = new Regex(@"\d+");
    MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(time1);
    if (matches.Count == 2)
    {
        int minutes = int.Parse(matches[0].Value);
        int seconds = int.Parse(matches[1].Value);
        return new TimeSpan(0, minutes, seconds);
    }
    return TimeSpan.Zero;
}
```